# can access docker container from other container but not from localhost

Tags: docker

I have an application which uses MySQL, Nest.js an Angular for the DB, Back and Front. I've managed to get Nest to communicate to the MySQL container nad (I suppose) Angular with Nest, but when I try to access the frontend from the browser it says that the site cant be reached, or that the server didn't answer if I do a request from Postman to the backend. I'm already exposing and assigning port ports but it isn't working.

I'm running `docker-compose up --build` , browsing `localhost:4200` or sending a request to `localhost:3000` and what I get from the browser is `localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on Chrome.

this is mi docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:

# MySQL
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

# Nest.js Backend
  server:
    build: ./backend
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./backend/src:/srv/app/bk-god/src

# Angular 6 Frontend
  client:
    build: ./frontend
    expose:
      - 4200
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/srv/app/fr-god/src
      - ./frontend/public:/srv/app/fr-god/public
    links:
      - server
```

And this is my Dockerfile on each folder [only difference is that backend runs Yarn run start:dev]:

```
FROM node:8.15.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /srv/app/fr-god
WORKDIR /srv/app/fr-god

COPY package.json /srv/app/fr-god
COPY yarn.lock /srv/app/fr-god

RUN yarn

COPY . /srv/app/fr-god
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

PS: MySQL is accessible through console and GUI, pointing to `localhost:3306`.

This is the `docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                    PORTS                               NAMES
435bfc1aa66d        docker_client       "yarn start"             About a minute ago   Up About a minute         0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp              docker_client_1
c96a84289d12        docker_server       "yarn run start:dev"     About a minute ago   Up About a minute         0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp              docker_server_1
069f8d61b770        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute         0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   docker_db_1
```

/etc/hosts content:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1               localhost
255.255.255.255         broadcasthost
::1                     localhost
```

logs from `docker logs docker_client_1`:

```
yarn run v1.12.3
$ ng serve
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2019-02-06T23:57:54.079Z
Hash: c0fd0f6da579440bf752
Time: 20737ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 85.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 240 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.83 MB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

logs from `docker logs docker_server_1`:

```
yarn run v1.12.3
$ nodemon
[nodemon] 1.18.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /srv/app/bk-god/src/**/*
[nodemon] starting `ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts`
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:33   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:33   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +201ms
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:40   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:40   [InstanceLoader] PlayerModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:40   [InstanceLoader] MatchModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:40   [RoutesResolver] PlayerController {/player}: +67ms
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:40   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +11ms
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:40   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, POST} route +2ms
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:40   [RoutesResolver] MatchController {/match}: +1ms
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:40   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:40   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, POST} route +8ms
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:40   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/detail, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 38   - 2019-2-6 23:57:40   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +8ms
```

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile as well? You need a  command  either in your dockerfile or docker-compose file to run the server. For example, in your docker-compose file something like this: `command: npm run dev`

Comment: Sure, I added its content to the question.

Comment: Exactly what command are you running, or what URL are you visiting?  What exact error are you getting?

Comment: @DavidMaze info added on second paragraph.

Comment: What is the output of `docker ps`?

Comment: @MichaelMiller added to the question. Haven't realized ports on the mysql container looks different than the other two, with an additional value after a comma. Do you know why is that?

Comment: 33060 is "exposed," meaning other docker containers on the same docker network can access the container over that port, however, port 3306 is mapped to your host at (0.0.0.0:3306).  This should work fine.  What if you try browsing localhost:3000?  You mentioned sending a request to it, but I'm wondering what you get back on a simple get request...  Can you paste the contents of your /etc/hosts file?  Also, what happens if you try navigating to http://127.0.0.1:3000, or http://127.0.0.1:4200?  Can you also paste the contents of `docker logs docker_client_1` and `docker logs docker_server_1`?

Comment: I've added both logs and /etc/hosts content. when I try to navigate to 127.0.0.1 I get the same response `This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/expose-vs-publish-docker-port-commands-explained-simply-434593dbc9a3) document makes me think that your "expose" declarations may be clobbering your "ports" declarations.  Try removing the "expose" declarations and reloading your containers.  This should fix your issue.

Comment: Tried without the expose but it keeps behaving as usual.